# .slideup() removing entire ul instead of just the nested li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, slideup

Having a few issues with this badboy:

Basically need it so that when one of the hidden lists collapses the markup is checked to see if there are any other 'active' lists already open, and to close those before a new one is opened. It looks messy if more than one is open at the same time.

**Link:**
http://www.matchboxlondon.com/ten/menu3/index.html

**Try:**
 1. Click Menu
 2. Click Services
 3. Click Pilates to expand
 
 4. Click Fitness to expand

**Problem:** Heading is also removed when .slideup() is used.

What my code is doing at the moment is checking to see if anything is opened with a globally defined variable called 'somethingOpen' - this is set to null on page load. This is all well and good BUT I feel it may have something to do with the complete display:none of the collapsable lists:

Because it's listy and nesty, I'll only include the js in here and not the markup:

```
somethingOpen = null; // to set after close and open

    $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {

        if (somethingOpen === true) { // first check
            $("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function () {
                $("#cssmenu > ul > li.active").removeClass('active').slideUp(); // <-- problem here
                somethingOpen = false; // closing so set to false
                return false; // exit function
            });
        } // End somethingOpen if

        // Open
        var checkElement = $(this).next(); // more checks
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); // add active class
        somethingOpen = true; // redefine if anything is open

        // Close
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            somethingOpen = false;
        }

        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        }

        // Returns
        if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }); // End click
```

Comment: first of all, same ID on multiple divs. id="cssmenu"

Comment: Can't you just add a custom class to the root <ul> when you click to open it? That way in the click bound event that handles the uncollapse, you state before doing so, and fadeOut or hide using the selector for uncollapsed, in return collapsing all?

Comment: The problem is slidesown() actually hides the element. this is ur issue. it sets the "display:none"

Comment: @Casey, when you mean the root <ul> do you mean the first <ul> in the cssmenu ID? Are you able to provide any kind of markup? Something like this perhaps?

http://jsfiddle.net/vgy0eyr4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that was interested, it needed a little tweaking, using children() and an after (>) to properly select the right element.

somethingOpen = null; // to set after close and open

```
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
    if (somethingOpen === true) { // first check
        $("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function () {
            $("#cssmenu").children('.active').removeClass('active');
            $("#cssmenu > ul > li > ul").slideUp('normal');
            somethingOpen = false; // closing so set to false
            return false; // exit function
        }); // end each
    }
}); // End somethingOpen if
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
//$("#cssmenu > ul > li.active").removeClass('active').slideUp(); // -- problem here

$("#cssmenu > ul > li.active").animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, 'fast');
```

Comment: Mmmm, but what that does is ignore the whole .active class element of the logic, so not ideal. But thanks all the same.